# Swift - Xcode complaining about extra argument - NSDate initialisation

Tags: ios, date, swift

I'm simply trying to initialise an NSDate object from epoch.
I have a dictionary object of type `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` and I know that this key corresponds to an Int

But the Swift compiler is complaining that the `NSDate` line has an `Extra argument 'timeIntervalSince1970' in call`

```
 if let respondedDate : Int = (responseDict["expiry_date"] as AnyObject) as? Int {
     let expiryDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: respondedDate)
 }
```

No idea what I am doing wrong here, this seems completely correct to me.
Any ideas?

Thanks for the timely response. Here's the working code!

```
if let respondedDate : NSTimeInterval = (responseDict["expiry_date"] as AnyObject) as? NSTimeInterval {
    let expiryDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: respondedDate)
}
```

Hopefully Xcode will be updated soon to make this error more descriptive rather than telling me that the there's an "extra argument"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's expecting `respondedDate` to be a `NSTimeInterval` which is a `Double`. If you cast respondedDate to `NSTimeInterval` instead it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `respondedDate` as an `NSTimeInterval` instead of an `Int`. Swift is strongly typed, so it isn't able to automatically cast an `Int` to `NSTimeInterval` (which is a typealias for `Double`).